# Grails nested g:each

Tags: grails, groovy

I am trying to loop through a list of fields in my index view. Lets say I pass the following to index.gsp:

```
[SomeDomainList: SomeDomain.list(), fields: ['field1', 'field2', 'field3']]
```

And then in index.gsp I have:

```
<g:each in="SomeDomainList" var="SomeDomainInstance">
    <g:each in="fields" var="field">
        <td>${SomeDomainInstance.field}</td>
    </g:each>
</g:each>
```

I would think that since the SomeDomainInstance variable gets evaluated that the field variable would get evaluated also. However, I get a "No such property: field for class: SomeDomain". I also tried:

```
<td>${SomeDomainInstance.${field}}</td>
```

But that results in a "Unclosed GSP expression" error. Can anyone tell me how I can achieve this?

Comment: try `<td>${SomeDomainInstance[field]}</td>`

Comment: this worked for me also... thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding double quotes to your example:

```
<td>${SomeDomainInstance."${field}"}</td>
```

You can just select the fields you're interested in using a criteria query and projections:

```
def domainList = SomeDomain.createCriteria().list {
    projections {
        property('field1')
        property('field2')
        property('field3')
    }
}

[SomeDomainList: domainList]
```

Or if you need the column names:

```
def domainList = SomeDomain.withCriteria{
    resultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP)
    projections {
        property( 'field1', 'field1')
        property( 'field2', 'field2')
        property( 'field3', 'field3')
    }
}

[SomeDomainList: domainList]
```

Comment: the double quotes worked... thanks! I can't believe I didn't think to try that myself.  Thanks for the additional help regarding criteria queries and projections, that will be useful.

Comment: If I remember correctly you can also use what @Mike-W suggests to execute functions using a string name. Somenthing along the line of `domainInstance."${stringFunctionName}"()`, groovy indeed. This could be helpful When testing.

Answer (score 0):

Why people love GStrings so much? A simple `subscript operator` would do:

```
<td>${SomeDomainInstance[ field ]}</td>
```